# Pass parameter to atexit()

Tags: c

On my program I am using a static variable (there is no way to do otherwise), and the problem is it needs to be free'd at exit.

How would I be able to achieve this without having to declare this variable as global ?

I was thinking of `atexit` function, but it doesn't seem to be able to take an argument. Isn't there any trick to pass my variable ?

Thanks.

Comment: Not clear: static variables **are** global and they ned not be `free`d by the application program. As you don't call `atexit` directly, so how would you pass anything? I smell an XY-problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that by "global", you mean you do not want to use a variable with file scope and that by "static" you are referring to a static local variable in a function rather than one of the other 19 meanings of the word.  You haven't given enough context, as there is undoubtedly a cleaner solution, but you could add a parameter to the function in which this variable is declared and do something like:

```
void
foo(int exit_flag, ...)
{ 
        static int * x = NULL
        if( exit_flag ){
                /* cleanup */
                free(x);
                return;
        }
        ...
}
```

Always call foo with exit_flag == 0, except in your exit handler when you set the exit_flag.

Comment: For some reason I haven't thought of it. I'll see if it can work with my code design. Thanks.

Comment: 'rather than one of the other 19 meanings of the word' ... hehe no, it's only overloaded that much in C++  :)

Answer (score 5):

Not sure if it meets your requirements, but I would make the static variable a file-scope static, off in one source file, something like this:

```
static char *my_static_variable = NULL;

static void my_cleanup_function()
{
    free(my_static_variable);
}

void my_initialization_function()
{
    my_static_variable = malloc(10);
    atexit(my_cleanup_function);
}
```

That is, `my_static_variable` and `my_cleanup_function` are visible only in that one source file; they are not program-wide globals.

As a side note, though, it is *not* typically necessary to free malloc'ed memory on exit.  Anything you allocate will, in effect, be automatically freed for you, by the operating system, when it releases the memory which had been used by your process.

Comment: Yup', however this is by using a global variable, which I'm not willing to do. I could as well free the global variable just before the return of main, it'd have the same effect. [EDIT]: Same as above, unfortunately you're using a global variable which I'm not willing to use. Yup', effectively memory is reclaimed by system but it's for a school project, it got to look nice !

Comment: @Ra'Jiska I understand.  I've clarified my answer to explain that you can make it a file-scope static variable, that's not truly global.

Comment: That's right, there doesn't seem to be 36 ways to do it properly, I'll give it quite some thoughts and see if it's the best way. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think that a better approach to address this issue is the use the `on_exit` function instead of the `atexit` function.

Please refer to the relevant man page - http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/on_exit.3.html

Comment: The exit status is exactly what I wanted to access. Shame that this is not POSIX, only a glibc extension. But newlib 3.0.0.20180226 has it :-)

Answer (score 0):

> How would I be able to achieve this without having to declare this variable as global ?

`static` storage class variables are a global -- they just aren't exported to the linker, so they can only be referenced in the same translation unit.

> I was thinking of `atexit` function, but it doesn't seem to be able to take an argument. Isn't there any trick to pass my variable ?

Yes. just register the handler with `atexit`:

```
static void* foo = NULL;

static void handler () {
  free(foo);
}

...

atexit(handler);
```

You don't really need to `free` memory though if you are exiting.  The system will clean it up.  Also there's no guarantee that your `atexit` handler will be called (e.g. SIGKILL).

Comment: OP does not say "`static`", but static.

Comment: Also `_exit()` does not call functions registered with `atexit()`.  There are other ways of avoiding such cleanup too, in a similar way.